# Inserting a node at the end of linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node {
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};

int main() {
  struct node* head = NULL;
  struct node* second = NULL;
  struct node* third = NULL;

  head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  third = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  head->data = 1;
  head->next = second;

  second->data = 2;
  second->next = third;

  third->data = 3;
  third->next = NULL;

  struct node* temp;
  temp = head;

  while (temp != NULL) { // for printing the linked list
    printf("%d ",temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
  }

  struct node* new1;
  struct node* temp1;

  temp1 = head;

  while (temp1 != NULL) { // for traversing to the end
    temp1 = temp1->next;
  }

  new1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  new1->data = 5;
  new1->next = NULL;

  temp1->next = new1;

  while (temp1 != NULL) { // again for printing the list
    printf("%d ",temp1->data);
    temp1 = temp1->next;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to insert a node at the end of my linked list, but it is not working. I created the linked list successfully but I am not able to insert a node at the end.
This is what my teacher taught me,  but it is not working.

Comment: What exactly is 'not working'?

Comment: After your `while(temp1 != NULL)` loop, `temp1` will be `NULL` so you can't dereference it.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: @interjay its working now but still i am getting this output - 1 2 3 3 5; instead the right output should be 1 2 3 1 2 3 5;

Comment: Update your question with the latest code and we have some chance of spotting what is still wrong! Your current code inserts 1 2 3 5 so can't produce either your "current" or expected outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, in the part that is commented

```
// for traversing to the end
```

the implementation iterates too far; the condition should be

```
while ( temp1->next != NULL )
```

to terminate as soon as the last node is reached, not if the terminating `NULL` pointer is reached.

Comment: its working now but still i am getting this output - 1 2 3 3 5; instead the right output should be 1 2 3 1 2 3 5; ?

Answer (score 2):

```
while(temp1 != NULL)          // for traversing to the end
{
    temp1 = temp1->next;
}
```

This will loop until `temp1` *is* `NULL`. You need to get the last node instead, i.e. when `temp1->next` is `NULL`, e.g.

```
while(temp1->next != NULL)          // for traversing to the end
{
    temp1 = temp1->next;
}
```